# angularJS: ng-show doesn't work with ng-app?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Why doesn't my ng-show work when I give ng-app a name and declare it?

https://jsfiddle.net/jzhang172/f7mrkf48/

```js
$(function(){
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
<form name="formMe">

1<input type="text"><br>
2<input type="text"><br>
Email<input name="email" ng-model="email" required>

<span ng-show="formMe.email.$touched">You touched me</span><br>
<input type="submit" ng-disabled="formMe.email.$invalid">
</form>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `name` attribute for your **form** and use that form name instead of module name `myApp` to validation form field. So use name property in your form tag `name="myForm"` and for validation use `myForm.email.$invalid`

like:

```
<form name="myForm">

    1<input type="text"><br>
    2<input type="text"><br>
    Email<input type="email" name="email" ng-model="email" required>

    <span ng-show="myForm.email.$touched">You touched me</span><br>
   <input type="submit" ng-disabled="myForm.email.$invalid">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code snippet has syntax error, the exact code snippet after fixing the error is working.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <form name="formMe">
    1
    <input type="text">
    <br>2
    <input type="text">
    <br>Email
    <input name="email" ng-model="email" required>
    <span ng-show="formMe.email.$touched">You touched me</span>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" ng-disabled="formMe.email.$invalid">
  </form>

</div>
```